# Too long time execution for LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join, execution

I have 2 table to join: 
"product" table, this table contains 257613 rows
and this is the structure:

```
id int(11) primary key autoincrement
id_category varchar(100)
name_category varchar(500)
name varchar(1000)
name_translated varchar(1000)
reference varchar(100)
link varchar(1000)
original_price varchar(45)
resell_price varchar(45)
active int(11)
ean varchar(16)
json_detail text
date_add date
date_update date
```

"stores_product" table, this table contains 181142 rows
and this is the structure:

```
id int(11) primary key autoincrement
reference varchar(128)
id_product int(11)
id_image_product int(11)
id_stock_product
id_store int(11)
```

and this is the incriminated slow query:

```
SELECT * FROM product AS p 
LEFT JOIN stores_product AS sp ON p.reference = sp.reference 
WHERE sp.id_store = 3
```

This query not get me a reply, I have blocked the execution after 35 minutes without a result.
Too many rows to process? Or I make an error in the query?

Comment: It look like that there are INDEXES missing. please show us the create of the tables **show create table product** and **show create table stores_product** and also the explain of your query **EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM product AS p 
LEFT JOIN stores_product AS sp ON p.reference = sp.reference 
WHERE sp.id_store = 3;**

Comment: Thanks for all your reply, I hare solved the problem, I have added the index: "reference" in the "product" table and "id_store" in table "stores_product" and the performace is improved

Comment: Each "store" has a separate "image" for each "product"?

Comment: @RickJames too much time has passed, I don't work on this project anymore, but if I remember good, yes
every product has a separate image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to note about this:

1. There is no benefit in doing an outer join, when you have a non-null condition on the joined field(s) (in your case `sp.id_store = 3`). Since outer joins are more costly than inner joins, use the latter in this case: `inner join`. The result is the same, but probably faster.
2. If on the other hand you had hoped to list *all* products by doing the outer join, then your query is incorrect. You then must move the condition out of the `where` clause into the `on` clause, like this:

   ```
   LEFT JOIN stores_product AS sp
          ON p.reference = sp.reference 
         AND sp.id_store = 3
   ```
3. The join condition does not look as expected. Normally, you would expect `sp.id_product = p.id`. But in comments you explain these two fields are unrelated. That is a very confusing way of naming things. You should consider storing a foreign key which references the primary key in the `product` table.
4. Depending on how your data is distributed, you will get a benefit from one of the following two indexes -- which you need to create: *stores_product(id_store, reference)* or *stores_product(reference, id_store)*.
5. Obviously *product(id)* should be a primary key.

Create the missing indexes, and look at the execution plan with `explain select ...` and see which are actually used.

Comment: The primary key of the 2 tables is the "id", "id" and "id_product" isn't related

Comment: "stores_table" not contains all product of the "product" table, if the left join return me null on "id_product" field I understand that isn't on one of my stores

Comment: I understand that you don't have all products of the product table in the stores table, ***but***, when you add a `= 3` condition on the joined table, you will *still* exclude records from your product table if that product does not exist in the *stores_table* table. So the effect of the `left join` is lost. That is what the first point is about. I have added another point (2) for how you can correct you query to get a real outer join.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are your performance saviour; use them.

```
SELECT * FROM product AS p 
LEFT JOIN stores_product AS sp
   ON p.reference = sp.reference   -- `p` needs INDEX(reference)
WHERE sp.id_store = 3  -- Needs  INDEX(id_store)
```

But there is more...

Your definitions of `reference` are inconsistent; fix that.

Remove the `LEFT`; you are not really doing a `LEFT JOIN`, since you are specifying `sp.id_store`.  And the query will run faster if it starts there.

`SELECT *` is fetching all columns from both tables; that seems like overkill.

Rethink your many `id` columns.  There seem to be more than you need.

If `reference` is really the unique identifier for `product`, then make it the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `id`.

[*How to make good indexes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you join 257613 rows with 181142 rows it just takes time.
The query is fine, I'm afraid you can't really to anything to increase performance other than upgrading you mysql-server.
Altough 35min seems extremly long, even for that amount of data.

You may also wan't to add primary keys, indexing and caching:

- [Optimization and Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)
- [How important a primary key can be for MySQL performance?](https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/04/04/how-important-a-primary-key-can-be-for-mysql-performance/)
- [The MySQL Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html)

Comment: I'll try to insert "reference" as index

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that indexes could be causing issues on row update or insert in a table. I advice to use temp tables. They are so far (as I know) the best way to reduce timing costs without changing anything in the database config. Dropping the temp table at the end is always a better practice.

So for the issue above. it could be a stored procedure that contains :

```
select reference, (the columns you need or just *) 
INTO #TempTable
from stores_product sp 
where sp.id_store = 3 

Select * 
from product AS p
left join #TempTable sp ON p.reference = sp.reference 

Drop table #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference to MySQL JOINS,

When writing `JOINS`, make sure that

1. `CHARSET(latin1, utf8)` of tables are same. ie. tables being joined should have same CHARSET type. This can be checked by `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`
2. Data type(`varchar, int..`) of joining column(which is used in `ON` condition) are also same.
3. Size of data types of joining columns are also same eg. `varchar(50)` `varchar(50)` will join faster than `varchar(50)` and `varchar(100)`
4. And not to say, JOINING column must be indexed.

Note: If Joins or any query as per say is taking time, always use `EXPLAIN` to check indexes being used and different stats to understand the execution plan.